# Rails - How to fire a callback on both old and new parents when child moves from one to the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

For examples case lets say you have

```
class Account << ActiveRecord

   has_many :receipts

   after_touch :calculate_sum

   def calculate_sum
      self[:total_sum] = receipts.sum(:value)
   end
end

class Receipt << ActiveRecord
   belongs_to :account, :touch => true
end
```

Each account should keep a total sum of all the receipts associated with it. 
If i update the value of an accounts receipt, the after_touch callback will be fired and the value is updated. All hunky dory there.

But if i change the parent on a receipt ie..

```
receipt = account_a.receipts.first
receipt.account = account_b
```

or

```
account_b.receipts << receipt
```

in these cases my callback doesnt get triggered on either the old or new account.

How do i make it so it does?

Answer (score 0):

You should use counter cache column for it [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)

1) Migration

```
def self.up
  add_column :accounts, :receipts_count, :integer, :default => 0

  Account.reset_column_information
  Account.all.each do |p|
    Account.update_counters p.id, :receipts_count => p.receipts.length
  end
end
```

2)

```
class Receipt << ActiveRecord
   belongs_to :account, :counter_cache => true
end
```

**UPDATE:**

This is a calculated field, accordingly to it we do not store it in the database and count it every time. We do not need to use callbacks. To solve this problem, create a method:

```
   def calculate_sum
     receipts.sum(:value)
   end
```

Comment: I know about rails counter cache columns but they are to store the count of child objects. In my case i want to store the sum of an attribute on my children. counter caches doesnt provide that out of the box.

Comment: yes your right, a receipt is a child of accounts. A receipt has an attribute @value. I want each account to keep track of the TOTAL VALUE of all child receipts - not the total count. I.e. if an account has two receipts, one with a value of 10$ and another of $50 then the accounts total_sum should = $60 (and not the count of receipts i.e. 2)